# ASP.NET calling a DataAdapter fill creates duplicate entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This strange behavior started today:

Code is very simple:(C# 4.5)

bool connOpened = OpenConnectiontoDB();

```
SqlCommand cmdCounties = new SqlCommand("spGetCounties", cn);
       cmdCounties.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       DataSet dsCounties = new DataSet();

       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
       da.SelectCommand = cmdCounties;

       try
       {
           da.Fill(dsCounties);

       }
```

If I run stored procedure spGetCounties directly (In DB) I get single values:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetCounties]

AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT c.tblCountyName,c.tblCountyID
    FROM
    tblCounty c
    ORDER BY 
    c.tblCountyName asc
END
```

tblCounty does not contain any duplicate values.

If I run the C# code  I look at values of dsCounties I see

```
A
A
B
B
C
C   
...
```

I call the stored procedure in the page_load Event.

```
  DataSet dsCounties = new DataSet();
                dsCounties = busLayer.GetCounties();
```

But this does not matter as I look at Database layer code , value of dsCounty is null and as soon as  da.Fill(dsCounties) runs i see duplicate values in dsCounties.

============================================

Update : 
After wasting 2 hours of my time and trying to trim down the code and compare it with previous versions I realize this behavior is due to a simple but stupid mistakes by others.

1: a new developer changed the Dev side config file to point to the Production DB!!!

2: Our glorious DB admin copied each row twice to the production!!! I cannot imagine how this can happen and forgot the put the County_ID as primary key.

I'm sorry if this question wasted your time.

Comment: OK I update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page load method, it will add the data every time the page is loaded.
You need to add

```
if(!PostBack)
{
     DataSet dsCounties = new DataSet();
     dsCounties = busLayer.GetCounties();
}
```

If it's postback, it means it's been loaded before. If not, the data set needs to be initialised.

Comment: I call it inside the !postback.  If you look at my question I say I look inside data layer C# code itself and I see dscounty is null and after calling sp it contains duplicate values. This has nothing to do with page this is all C#

Comment: This was not my code, see my edit. I appreciate your time trying to help +1.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it is the most likely scenario for this issue to happen.